# delphi symbol row to ansi code

Tags: delphi

I need to make some simple program ,but I don't know to start with.
For example ,I got symbol row - 1m213p03a - and this row need to convert to ANSI code ,but only these letter "m", "p" ,"a". In result need to got this - 1109213112397
I need to make this with forms ,and this symbol row need to write user ,who use this program.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Since conversion algorithm you are looking for is quite simple, I decided to give you an answer. But you should have tried to write some code yourself first, and then when you get stuck ask for help with specific code.

Comment: What happened to the '0'?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you head start with conversion algorithm. It should work in all Delphi versions. Algorithm is searching through input string characters, if character is number then it is written in result string as-is, otherwise it is converted to decimal ANSI representation of underlying character.

```
function Convert(const input: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(input) do
    if input[i] in ['0' .. '9'] then result := result + input[i]
    else result := result + IntToStr(Ord(input[i]));
end;

var
  s: string;

s := Convert('1m213p03a');
```